# How to create an object the nested values in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a set of data that I wanted to create an object from, everything works well except that the inner nested object has 3 elements but only the last element is being printed. Below is my object structure

```
  [

    {
         "item_id": 696136507565,
         "seller_id": 2549116888,
         
         "sku": [
            {
                "cart_id": 131, 
                "sku_id": 4939047817461,
            },
            {
                "cart_id": 131, 
                "sku_id": 4939047817463,
            },
            {   
                "cart_id": 131,
                "sku_id": 4939047817466, 
            }
         ],
     },
     
     {
         "item_id": 729563966440,
         "seller_id": 2211628865398,
         
         "sku": [
            {
                "cart_id": 132, 
                "sku_id": 894758674833,
            },
            {
                "cart_id": 132, 
                "sku_id": 4939047387945,
            },
            {   
                "cart_id": 132,
                "sku_id": 1243567817466, 
            }
         ],
     },
 ]
```

I needed to create an object of the below structure

```
checkList:{
      seller_id:{
        seller_id: boolean,
        item_id:{
            sku_id: boolean,
            sku_id: boolean,
            sku_id: boolean,
        },
        
        item_id:{
            sku_id: boolean,
            sku_id: boolean,
            sku_id: boolean,
        },
      },
}
```

so my expected result from my new object will look like below:

```
 {
 
    "2549116888": {
        "2549116888": false,
        "696136507565": {
            "696136507565": false,
            //sku
            "4939047817461": false,
            "4939047817463": false,
            "4939047817466": false,
        }
    },
    
    "2211628865398": {
        "2211628865398": false,
        "729563966440": {
            "729563966440": false,
            //sku
            "894758674833": false,
            "4939047387945": false,
            "1243567817466": false,
        }
    },
 
 }
```

but this below is what I was able to come up with, only the last element of each sku is printed and the others are not printed:

```
 {
 
    "2549116888": {
        "2549116888": false,
        "696136507565": {
            "696136507565": false,
            //sku
    
            "4939047817466": false,
        }
    },
    
    "2211628865398": {
        "2211628865398": false,
        "729563966440": {
            "729563966440": false,
            //sku

            "1243567817466": false,
        }
    },
 
 }
```

Below is the code that I have tried so far

```
let myNewObj = {}

myObj?.map((value) =>{
         value?.sku?.map((val,key) =>{
            let skuObj = {
              ...skuObj,
              [val.sku_id]: false 
            }
            myNewObj ={...myNewObj,
              [value.seller_id]:{
                [value.seller_id]: false,
                [value.item_id]:{
                    [value.item_id]: false,
                    [val.sku_id]: false,
                },
                  
              },
            }
         })
      })

      
  }
```

How can I modify my code to get the result I wanted and print all the sku with boolean values. Thanks in advance

Comment: The spread object will have any duplicate properties overwritten by the new `[value.seller_id]`, you will need to combine the properties at each "level", if you want to add into existing objects rather than replace them in each loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with your current code is that it's overwriting the `myNewObj` and `skuObj` objects in each iteration of the map function. This means that only the last `sku_id` and `item_id` for each `seller_id` are being stored in `myNewObj`.

I have changed the code to help you acheive that, here is the updated code:

```js
let checkList = {};

myObj?.forEach((value) => {
  if (!checkList[value.seller_id]) {
    checkList[value.seller_id] = { [value.seller_id]: false };
  }

  if (!checkList[value.seller_id][value.item_id]) {
    checkList[value.seller_id][value.item_id] = {};
  }

  value?.sku?.forEach((sku) => {
    checkList[value.seller_id][value.item_id][sku.sku_id] = false;
  });
});
```

Comment: I appreciate you guy for your help all the answers prodiver works like charm, I just decided to go for this as my prefered answer because i see it more simplier to easier to understand

Answer (score 0):

You could map new entries for objects.

```js
const
    data = [{ item_id: 696136507565, seller_id: 2549116888, sku: [{ cart_id: 131, sku_id: 4939047817461 }, { cart_id: 131, sku_id: 4939047817463 }, { cart_id: 131, sku_id: 4939047817466 }] }, { item_id: 729563966440, seller_id: 2211628865398, sku: [{ cart_id: 132, sku_id: 89475867483 }, { cart_id: 132, sku_id: 493904738794 }, { cart_id: 132, sku_id: 1243567817466 }] }],
    result = Object.fromEntries(data.map(({ seller_id, item_id, sku }) => [seller_id, {
        [seller_id]: false,
        [item_id]: {
            [item_id]: false, 
            ...Object.fromEntries(sku.map(({ sku_id }) => [sku_id, false]))
        }
    }]));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) approach

```js
const input = [{ "item_id": 696136507565, "seller_id": 2549116888, "sku": [{ "cart_id": 131, "sku_id": 4939047817461, }, { "cart_id": 131, "sku_id": 4939047817463, }, { "cart_id": 131, "sku_id": 4939047817466, } ], }, { "item_id": 729563966440, "seller_id": 2211628865398, "sku": [{ "cart_id": 132, "sku_id": 894758674833, }, { "cart_id": 132, "sku_id": 4939047387945, }, { "cart_id": 132, "sku_id": 1243567817466, } ], }, ]

const output = input.reduce((result, current) => {
  if (current.seller_id && !result[current.seller_id]) {
    //initialize a new attribute with `seller_id`
    result[current.seller_id] = {
      [current.seller_id]: false
    }
  }

  if (current.item_id && !result[current.seller_id][current.item_id]) {
    //initialize a new attribute with `item_id`
    result[current.seller_id][current.item_id] = {
      [current.item_id]: false
    }
  }

  if (result[current.seller_id][current.item_id]) {
    //add sku items under `item_id`
    for (const skuItem of current.sku) {
      if (skuItem.sku_id) {
        result[current.seller_id][current.item_id][skuItem.sku_id] = false;
      }
    }
  }

  return result;
}, {})

console.log(output);
```